# Which is the best way to send data from a service to activity on a button click?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a floating widget in my app. I want to pass data from the floating widget service to activity when I click a button on the floating widget.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: LocalBroadcastManager could help you.

Comment: You can use an `intent` and put extra data in it with `putExtra()`-method

Comment: Hi @Eugene, isn't LocalBroadcastManager deprecated ?

Comment: Hello @CodeIsLaw, I don't want to launch the activity. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Yes, because of Room, LiveData and so on. But if you don't want them, why not LocalBroadcastManager?